# Why is my Caps Lock not working as Ctrl?

Tags: 12.10, keyboard-layout, capslock

I am on a Lenovo W500 with German keyboard layout. I use Ubuntu 12.10 and have configured my keyboard layout to use the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. But it does not work. I even tried to reboot my system.

Here is the configuration of my "Keyboard Layout".

My goal is to have <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> as <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> plus the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> as <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

[image: screenshot of keyboard layout settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all three keys to behave as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> by only checking the `Caps Lock as Ctrl` checkbox. The `At bottom left` option seems to not work as expected and should be left unchecked.

Comment: Now everything works as expected :)